# as3, MySQL PHP connection

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

am trying to connect my flash project with database. However, i want to be able to submit and retrieve data from database having 3 fields (name, score and date). My problem is that if I click submit button and when i go to check in database i only see 0 score meaning nothing is submitted. Can someone help me on this. Tq 
Here is my coding for flash:

```
var str:String = "";
var myscore = 0;
btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitted);

function submitted(e:MouseEvent)
{
var myrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/Y/sendscore.php");
myrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.name = str;
variables.score = myscore;
myrequest.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad);
loader.load(myrequest);
}

function dataOnLoad(evt:Event)
{
MC_success.alpha=100;
//status is a custom flag passed from back-end 
}
```

MY PHP CODE FOR SENDING DATA;

```
<?php
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

        //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $name = clean($_POST['name']);
    $score = clean($_POST['score']);
        $currentdate = date("Y/m/d");

    //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "INSERT INTO highscores(user, score, date) VALUES('$name','$score','$currentdate')";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
echo "writing=Ok";
exit();
mysql_close();  

?>
```

MY PHP CODE TO RETRIEVE DATA;

```
<?php   
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

        //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score ASC";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);
if($num > 10)
{$num = 10;}
//echo "writing=Ok";

echo "<b><center>Best Times:</center></b><br /><table>";

$i=0;
$i2=1;
while ($i < $num) {

$name=mysql_result($result,$i,"user");
$time=mysql_result($result,$i,"score");
$date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");


echo "<tr><td align=left valign=top>$i2.</td><td align=center valign=top><b>$name</b> | $score | $date</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><hr></td></tr>";
$i2++;
$i++;
}
echo "</table>";
//$urlRefresh = "scores.php";
//header("Refresh: 15; URL=\"" . $urlRefresh . "\"");

exit();
mysql_close();


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've missed out some piece of code whereby the score is changed, you're actually declaring `var myscore = 0` right at the top of your AS3 code block.

The first thing would be to change that to `100`, then run you script and see if that modified score variable is getting submitted. If it is, then everything is working as it should.

**Update:**

You've changed your question, and you want to be able to load data. You already have a function set up for this via `loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad)`. You just need to grab the data your PHP script is sending back. This can be accessed via your `evt` parameter in the `dataOnLoad` function:

```
function dataOnLoad(evt:Event):void {   
    trace("Data submission complete");
    var returnVars = evt.target.data;

    trace("***********************");

    for (var myVars in returnVars) {
        trace(myVars + ": " + returnVars[myVars]);
    }

    trace("***********************");
}
```

**Update 2:**

You've requested help with loading your scores from the database. As you already have a PHP file that retrieves this from the database (let's assume it's called `scores.php`),m you just need a function in Flash to load it.

You already have the basic functions in place, making use of `URLLoader` and Event Listeners. You just need these to apply to a straightforward load:

```
btn_scores.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadScores);

function loadScores(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoresLoadComplete);

    fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("scores.php"));
}

function scoresLoadComplete(evt:Event):void {
    try {
        var returnVars = evt.target.data;

        trace("***********************");
        for (var myVars in returnVars) {
            trace(myVars + ": " + returnVars[myVars]);
        }
        trace("***********************");
    } catch (err:Error) {
        trace("Can't parse loaded file: " + err.message);
    }
}
```

**Note** that your PHP file currently returns an HTML table of results. This won't behave in Flash; you'd be much better off sending through key/value pairs and parsing them or just a basic HTML list of scores.

Comment: Yes bro, i changed and it shows score = 100 on database, however my aim is to send name and score entered by user. would you pliz help me on this. I appreciate Tq.

Comment: I've tried to work with that code u gave above but it looks like it confirms submission to database. coz my idea is to put a button where a user can click to view the stored names and score may you plz modify the code above with a button to lessen my burden Tq.

Comment: @mchucha I've updated the answer again. I think you need to do some research into how loading, Events & Listeners work in AS3 before you go much further.

Comment: All your ideas works perfect bro, I though still figure out a way to make these data appear in my flash panel. i made a button as u showed me and set all connection seem to work. However, I have to have something to display the data in flash and that is my challenge part. I really do not know how to accomplish this. Help me bro if there is a way. Tq to you again.

Comment: @mchucha Simply create a textfield with an instance name of `highscores` on your stage. You'll need to update your PHP script to return something like `echo "scores=<b><center>Best Times:...` - so that you're prepending the returned string with **`scores=`** and then, in the `scoresLoadComplete` function, add this line in the `try` block: `highscores.htmlText = returnVars.scores;`

Comment: I tried to put that, but it give me this error Can't parse loaded file: Error #1069: Property scores not found on String and there is no default value.

Comment: @mchucha Without seeing your code, it's impossible to diagnose. Put the contents of your `scores.php` file on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and I should be able to see what the issue is.

Comment: Yes bro @indextwo i put already both score.php and my flash file in pasterbin as you instructed. Tq

Comment: @mchucha... and the link to that pastebin is...?

Comment: @mchucha As I mentioned in my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476568/as3-mysql-php-connection/26483673?noredirect=1#comment41615383_26483673), you need to modify your PHP file to output a **`scores`** var. Update this line: `echo "<b><center>Best Times:</center></b><br /><table>";` (**line 25** in your pastebin code) to read `echo "scores=<b><center>Best Times:</center></b><br /><table>";`.

Comment: brother @indextwo i tried this also but it still gives same error and when i display php page in browser it shows "scores" is included in list of displayed objects. I think bcoz it is inside double quotes or? btw is my flash coding sounds okay?

Comment: @mchucha I think, at this point, this has become a completely different question. My post answers both your original question and two further ones; I'd recommend accepting my answer and then posting your issue as a [completely new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to save any confusion.

Comment: Aw I understand brother @indextwo. Btw how do i accept your answer? where shld i go?. I post it as new question as you suggested help me bro, i really do not sleep of this project.

Comment: @mchucha Just click on the check mark next to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26483673/988246) to accept it.

Comment: I tried to change the line highscores.htmlText = returnVars.score; to highscores.text = returnVars; but it displays all content of html settings found in php together with data. Is there a way to fix it so as to display only data in flash?