# FLASH, PHP, MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, flash

am creating my flash project that accepts 4 variables i.e. name, school, score and date. However the connection between FLASH, PHP and MYSQL works fine and i can send data to MySQL database via flash with no problem. Now my problem is that i can't retrieve and view the data back to flash. I created a textfield named highscores for retrieving data in flash. And am sure my php code for retrieving is fine since i can view data in browser. So is there a way to retrieve my data in flash? here is my coding for flash:

```
 str.text = "";
    myschool.text = "";
    myscore.text = "";

    //Here i declared a textfield named highscores
    //var text:String = highscores.text;


    btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitted);

    function submitted(e:MouseEvent)
    {

    if(!str.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
    } 
    else if (!myschool.length) {
       status_txt.text = "Please enter your school name";
    }
    else if (!myscore.length) {
       status_txt.text = "Please enter your score";
    }
    else {
        var myrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/Y/sendscore.php");
    myrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.name = str.text;
    variables.school = myschool.text;
    variables.score = myscore.text;

    myrequest.data = variables;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad);
    loader.load(myrequest);
    }
    }

    function dataOnLoad(evt:Event)
    {

        trace("Data submission complete");
        var returnVars = evt.target.data;

        trace("***********************");

        for (var myVars in returnVars) {
            trace(myVars + ": " + returnVars[myVars]);
        }

        trace("***********************");

    MC_success.alpha=100;
    //status is a custom flag passed from back-end 
    }

    btn_scores.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadScores);

    function loadScores(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoresLoadComplete);

        fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/Y/scores.php"));


    }

    function scoresLoadComplete(evt:Event):void {
        try {

            var returnVars = evt.target.data;
            highscores.htmlText = returnVars;
            trace("Data retrieved successfully");
            for (var myVars in returnVars) {
                trace(myVars + ": " + returnVars[myVars]);
            }

            trace("***********************");
            //highscores.htmlText = returnVars.scores;
        } catch (err:Error) {
            trace("Can't parse loaded file: " + err.message);
        }



    }
```

HERE IS MY PHP CODE FOR RETRIEVING DATA

```
<?php   
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

        //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);
if($num > 10)
{$num = 10;}
//echo "writing=Ok";

echo "<b><center>Best Times:</center></b><br /><table>";
//echo "scores=<b><center>Best Times:</center></b><br /><table>";

$i=0;
$i2=1;
while ($i < $num) {

$name=mysql_result($result,$i,"user");
$school=mysql_result($result,$i,"school");
$score=mysql_result($result,$i,"score");
$date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");


echo "<tr><td align=left valign=top>$i2.</td><td align=center valign=top><b>$name</b> <b> | $school</b> | $score | $date</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><hr></td></tr>";
$i2++;
$i++;
}
echo "</table>";
//$urlRefresh = "scores.php";
//header("Refresh: 15; URL=\"" . $urlRefresh . "\"");

exit();
mysql_close();


?>
```

Comment: Does `dataOnLoad` ever get called?

Comment: @ ethrbunny yes i called it in function dataOnLoad(evt:Event).... or maybe you explain a little bit. tq

Comment: You *declared* it - I'm wondering if the POST callback ever occurs.

Comment: So may you pliz show me a way referring on my above flash code? am not outstanding programmer though.@ ethrbunny

Comment: I tried to change the line highscores.htmlText = returnVars.score; to highscores.text = returnVars; but it displays all content of html settings found in php together with data. Is there a way to fix it so as to display only data in flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26483673/988246), a textfield in Flash won't play well with HTML tables.

In your PHP file, you need to replace everything between the first and last `echo` with the following:

```
echo "scores=<b>Best Times:</b><br />";

$i = 0;
$i2 = 1;

while ($i < $num) {
    $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"user");
    $school = mysql_result($result,$i,"school");
    $score = mysql_result($result,$i,"score");
    $date = mysql_result($result,$i,"date");

    echo "$i2. <b>$name</b> | <b>$school</b> | $score | $date <br />";

    $i2++;
    $i++;
}
```

Note that I have added back the **`scores=`** variable. This *shouldn't* cause any issues, as long as you're using the following line in AS3:

`highscores.htmlText = returnVars.scores;`

Separating your variables into name/value pairs means that you can pass other variables from PHP if you need to.

**Update:**

Having taken a look at your files, the whole thing runs perfectly; it successfully submits to the database and loads data back. However:

**I think the issue you're having is with Flash *caching* your scores.php file.**

This is fairly common when doing a `URLRequest()` on a file you've previously loaded. The most straightforward way to deal with this is to change this line:

```
fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/Y/scores.php"));
```

To this:

```
fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/Y/scores.php?rand=" + Math.random() * 999999));
```

All that does is add a random number to the end of your load as the 'garbage' variable `rand`. Flash sees this as you loading a different file, and so makes a fresh request rather than pulling it from the cache.

Other than that, everything in your files seems to run exactly as it should.

Comment: I tried this it displays nice in browser but again it gives same error in flash Can't parse loaded file: Error #1069: Property score not found on String and there is no default value. btw what is the variable score for? @indextwo

Comment: @mchucha Sorry, my mistake - you should be pulling `returnVars.scores` - plural, not singular. As I mentioned, having the value in a variable means you can add other variables to your PHP output. If you prefer, you can probably take that out and just dump `returnVars` into your textfield. If that works, just remember to remove `scores=` from your `echo`.

Comment: I tried to make plural but it doesn't but after i take out .scores and remove also from echo it displays this in text field "connection okayBest Times:" but no data is retrieved then @indextwo

Comment: @mchucha Just to confirm: is your textfield set to multiline in Flash? By default they're not. It sounds like it's loading your information fine, but not showing anything after `Best times:` because that's followed by a new line.

Comment: Yes i set it to dynamic text field and multiline @indextwo. Btw is there a way i can send you my files so that you can have a close look to them e.g E-mail Tq?

Comment: @mchucha Zip up your PHP, Flash and SQL files and put them on Dropbox or YouSendIt and put the link here. I will try to take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Okay bro @indextwo here are my 5 files; 3 php files 1 flash and 1 a notepad just to give you instructions so that you can create same database like the one i used in xamp phpMyadmin. Tq https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4qzjuzq5pi4lck/mchucha_as3_php_mysql.rar?dl=0

Comment: Thanx brother @indextwo. Finally it works the way i want. Thank you for your help your favor is quite immeasurable. I don know how to thank you.

Comment: @mchucha Accepted answer is good enough! You can always throw in an upvote if you want too ;)

Comment: yes i understand bro @indextwo, however i don know how to say. This was really burden to me omg! Btw is there a way i cn communicate with you personally coz sometimes i feel shy to ask though i h've many probs in hand. Tq